# ASP.NET Web API Help Page package does not get all api endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

I installed ASP.NET 4 Web API Help Page package via nuget to my Web Api project. For some reason it does not display all the api endpoints. I have the documentation set to use XML. Not sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated.

Here is an example controller

```
    public class ProductController : BaseController
    {
        // GET api/Product/Get/5/43324
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public ApiProduct Get(int id, [FromUri]int productId)
        {
             //// logic
        }
   }
```

routes

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "api-info",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the controllers for which they are not showing up?

Comment: updated the question to show the controller, also not all endpoints for a controller are displayed.

Comment: also could you share the routes?

Comment: @KiranChalla: Updated the routes as well.

Comment: HelpPage which depends on ApiExplorer removes the api help descriptions if it sees possibility of ambiguity in resolving the actions. Looking at your above action and route, help page should have shown you something like 'api/Product/Get/{id}?productId={productId}'...its not entirely clear just from the information above as to why you are seeing the issue...it would help to share more info..

Comment: Not sure what additional information I should post. I tried creating a plain simple controller which does not show up. I will keep debugging.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32590/discussion-between-kiran-challa-and-tmjam)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue, the problem here is, In Web API there is no action and methods are mapped to the verb and arguments directly, Updating my route to this fixed the problem and all the routes show up.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "apsi-info",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above solution doesn't solve your problem - take a look and make sure you aren't defining BOTH the AcceptVerbs attribute and its shortcut:

```
public class ProductController : BaseController
{
    // GET api/Product/Get/5/43324
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ApiProduct Get(int id, [FromUri]int productId)
    {
         //// logic
    }
```

}

Remove one of them and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why a HTTP method might not be available, either as an endpoint or not showing up in the autogenerated help:

The function might be `private` and not `public`.

---

Will show up:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCount()
{
    return Ok(db.Projects.Count());
}
```

Won't show up:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/projects")]
private IHttpActionResult GetCount()
{
    return Ok(db.Projects.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be helpful for someone with different problem statement, As I faced similar sort of issue and wasted few hours.

```
[PUT("Update/booking/{id}")]
public bool Put(id bookingId, [FromBody] BookingEntity bookingEntity)
```

This api endpoint won't appear in API help page. 
If you observe parameter name is different in route that is {id} and method parameters "bookingId". Both should be same as specified in below code.

```
[PUT("Update/booking/{id}")]
public bool Put(id id, [FromBody] BookingEntity bookingEntity)
```